# Single file uploads which aren't multiform/form-data in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

The Laravel documentation provides pretty detailed documentation about [form based uploads](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#files). However, the documentation only handles form uploads (`multipart/form-data`) and nothing about how to handle uploads where the uploaded file is the request body itself (how you may use it for APIs). For example a requests which contains `application/zip` or `application/xml` as `Content-Type` and file itself as the request body. The `Illuminate\Http\Request` doesn't seem to contain any methods for that either.

In short: How can I handle file uploads which are **NOT** `multipart/form-data` requests?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this method is never documented anywhere, but `getContent()` (in `Illuminate\Http\Request`) does return the body of the request as string or resource.